# Displaying duplicates in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, duplicates

I have the following sql query:

```
SELECT `PARTNER_NAME` 
FROM `PARTNER` 
WHERE `PARTNER_CODE` IN 
                    (SELECT 
                    `PARTNER_CODE` 
                    FROM INBOUND_ORDER 
                    WHERE `AWB_NUM` IN 
                                ( SELECT 
                                `INBOUND_ORDER_AWB_NUM` 
                                FROM DUTY_EXEMPTION 
                                WHERE `DE_SENT_SUBMISSION` IS NOT NULL 
                                    AND `CARGO_TO_UNHRD`IS NULL
                                ) 
                    )
```

How can I display the duplicate records as well

Comment: Add some sample table data, current result and the expected result. So we can see the difference!

Comment: try this query - SELECT P.`PARTNER_NAME` FROM `PARTNER` P 
INNER JOIN INBOUND_ORDER IO ON P.PARTNER_CODE = IO.PARTNER_CODE
INNER JOIN DUTY_EXEMPTION DE ON IO.AWB_NUM = DE.INBOUND_ORDER_AWB_NUM
WHERE DE.`DE_SENT_SUBMISSION` IS NOT NULL AND DE.`CARGO_TO_UNHRD`IS NULL

Comment: @RakeshKumar Thanks!! works perfectly

Comment: Check explanation in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using so Much inner Query use this with join:-

```
SELECT P.PARTNER_NAME FROM PARTNER P INNER JOIN INBOUND_ORDER IO ON P.PARTNER_CODE = IO.PARTNER_CODE INNER JOIN DUTY_EXEMPTION DE ON IO.AWB_NUM = DE.INBOUND_ORDER_AWB_NUM WHERE DE.DE_SENT_SUBMISSION IS NOT NULL AND DE.CARGO_TO_UNHRDIS NULL
```

Your query have unexpected behavior due to

```
WHERE `AWB_NUM` IN 
( SELECT `INBOUND_ORDER_AWB_NUM` FROM DUTY_EXEMPTION 
WHERE `DE_SENT_SUBMISSION`
IS NOT NULL AND `CARGO_TO_UNHRD`IS NULL)
```

It will return only first record returned by

```
( SELECT `INBOUND_ORDER_AWB_NUM` FROM DUTY_EXEMPTION 
    WHERE `DE_SENT_SUBMISSION`
    IS NOT NULL AND `CARGO_TO_UNHRD`IS NULL)
```